# Putting '\0' mid-string to terminate it early won't work

Tags: c, arrays, null, terminator

I wanted to create a program where it'll take a Linux input command, like pwd -P and do something with it. What I want to do, is put them in a string where the space ' ' char is replaced with the null terminator '\0', so it'll look something like "pwd\0-P". Then with that, I could have array[0] pointing to the start of the string, and have array[1] pointing to the portion after the '\0' so I would have 2 separate strings -> array[0] = "pwd" and array[1] = "-P".
This is all so I can use exec(array[0],array);

My problem is that when I do that, the null terminator doesn't terminate the string after "pwd", and my string ends up becoming "pwd-P" where there are no spaces in between.

The string that I'm doing all of this with is "check"

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
char ch;
pid_t pid;
int i=0;
int flag = 0;
int word = 0;
int count = 0;
char check[100],temp[100];
char * array[100];
printf("Your Command> ");
strcpy(check,"");

//command stuff
array[word] = check;
temp[i]='\0';

while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
    count = count+1;
    if(ch != '&' && ch != ' '){
        strcpy(temp,&ch);
        strcat(check,temp);
    }
    else if(ch == ' '){
        check[count] = '\0';
        word = word+1;
        array[word] = &check[count];
        }
    else if(ch == '&'){
        flag =1;
        check[count] = 0;
    }

}

//end of command stuff


if(flag!=1){
    check[count] = '\0';
}
word = word+1;
puts(check);
array[word] = &check[count];
    //fork process stuff


if((pid = fork())==0){
    printf("hello from child\n");
    printf("%s\n",array[0]);
    printf("%s\n",array[1]);
    printf("%s\n",array[2]);
    execvp(array[0], array);
}
else{
    if(flag == 0){
        wait(NULL);
        printf("hello from parent\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("hello from parent (no wait)\n");
    }
}   
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: `quack` has no definition in the code presented.

Comment: `strcpy(temp,&ch);` is illegal as `ch` is a char - it is not a string

Comment: SORRY! That was mean to be temp. I think I missed it when I was trying to relabel it

Comment: Please make sure that your code is a [mcve].

Comment: Do you want `strtok`?

Comment: I've looked at strtok but unsure how to use it in this case

Comment: You would apply `strtok` to the problem by reading in a whole line at once -- maybe via `fgets()`, though a `getchar` loop would still work -- and then extracting the individual words via `strtok()`.  The effect on the buffer into which you initially read the line will be exactly what you describe wanting.

Comment: Thanks that really helped. strtok wasn't in the default set of functions I learned in class but using it was certainly a very easy fix to my problem!